# Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to implement dark theme from fragment named as "Fragment_One" in android studio.
This is from that fragment file

```
                              if (!isChecked) {
                                   AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                                   isChecked = true;
                               } else {
                                   AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                                    isChecked = false;
                               }
```

It is giving error in MainActivity in the following line of onRequestPermissionsResult() method

```
    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

The onRequestPermissionsResult() method is as follows:

```
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission granted on request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                files= getAllFiles(this);
                FragmentTransaction f_fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                f_fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainFragment, new Fragment_Two()).commit();
            }
            if (grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
        }
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0]  + grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"allow settings ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"permission denied ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: array grantResults is empty, but you trying to access it's first element

Comment: Before applying the themes , it is working fine.

Comment: where you requested permissions ?

Comment: It is in MainActivity

Comment: Try adding request permission in your fragment.See if it works or not.

Comment: It is giving the same error at the same line